# Python regex replace capture

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add one space before and after `+-`, using `re.sub` (only) what expression to use?

```
import re

text = """a+b
a+b-c
a + b - c
a+b-c+d-e
a + b - c + d - e"""

text = re.sub('(\s?[+-]\s?)', r' \1 ', text)
print(text)
```

expected result:

```
a + b
a + b - c
a + b - c
a + b - c + d - e
a + b - c + d - e
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="python">
  <code data-type="sample-code">
    import re

    text = """a+b
      a+b-c
      a + b - c
      a+b-c+d-e
      a + b - c + d - e
      """

    text = re.sub('(\s?[+-]\s?)', r' \1 ', text)
    print(text)
  </code>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that if `-` or `+` are consecutive, `re.sub('\s?([+-])\s?', r' \1 ', text)` won't work well as there will be double spaces in the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try capturing *only* the `[+-]`, and then replace with that group surrounded by spaces:

```
text = re.sub('\s?([+-])\s?', r' \1 ', text)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="python">
  <code data-type="sample-code">
import re

text = """a+b
a+b-c
a + b - c
a+b-c+d-e
a + b - c + d - e
"""

text = re.sub('\s?([+-])\s?', r' \1 ', text)
print(text)
  </code>
</div>
```

You also might consider repeating the `\s`s with `*` instead of `?`, so that, for example, `3   + 5` gets prettified to `3 + 5`:

```
\s*([+-])\s*
```

Comment: why I'm not thinking about that :lol: will accepted in few minutes, thanks.

Comment: why `\s*` can match if there is no space?

Comment: Because `*` means repeat the previous token *zero or more times* (compared to `?`, which means repeat the previous token *zero or one time*)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `lambda` function with `re.sub`:

```
import re
new_text = re.sub('(?<=\S)[\+\-](?=\S)', lambda x:f' {x.group()} ', text)
```

Output:

```
a + b
a + b - c
a + b - c
a + b - c + d - e
a + b - c + d - e
```